# Aggregate nc file using specific condition in R

Tags: r, aggregate, netcat

I need your help again.
I have .nc file, metadata:
File minty.nc (NC_FORMAT_64BIT):

```
 1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    short mn2t[longitude,latitude,time]   
        scale_factor: 0.000940940342005054
        add_offset: 259.294916797895
        _FillValue: -32767
        missing_value: -32767
        units: K
        long_name: Minimum temperature at 2 metres since previous post-processing

 3 dimensions:
    longitude  Size:57
        units: degrees_east
        long_name: longitude
    latitude  Size:49
        units: degrees_north
        long_name: latitude
    time  Size:90240
        units: hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0
        long_name: time
        calendar: gregorian

2 global attributes:
    Conventions: CF-1.6
```

I have a code, which works well with smaller .nc files:

```
 library(raster)
 library(rgdal)
 library(ggplot2)
 nc_data = nc_open('file.nc')
 lon = ncvar_get(nc_data, "longitude")
 lat = ncvar_get(nc_data, "latitude", verbose = F)
 t = ncvar_get(nc_data, "time")
 head(lon)
 head(t)
 head(lat)
 mint.array = ncvar_get(nc_data, "mn2t")
 dim(mint.array)
 fillvalue = ncatt_get(nc_data, "mn2t", "_FillValue")
 fillvalue
 mint.array[mint.array == fillvalue$value] <- NA
 r_brick <- brick(mint.array, xmn=min(lat), xmx=max(lat), ymn=min(lon), ymx=max(lon), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))
 r_brick = flip(t(r_brick), direction = 'y')
```

Because of the large file size, I got an error: "cannot allocate vector of size 1.4 Mb"
I also used gc() to clear unused memory. It didn't help.
I do not need all the data in my file.nc. In this case, I need somehow to aggregate this. For my further calculations, I need only daily minima. In this case, for df I used:
`df(ff) <- aggregate(df, list(rep(1:(nrow(df)%(%n+1), each=24, len=nrow(df))), min)`

Unfortunately, I find it difficult to adapt this code for .nc file. Maybe someone could help me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid memory problems, you can do this instead:

```
library(raster)
r_brick <- brick('file.nc', "mn2t")
```

It also prevents mistakes. For example, in your code, this is wrong in two ways:

```
xmn=min(lat), xmx=max(lat), ymn=min(lon), ymx=max(lon)
```

because `x` should be `lon` and `y` should be `lat` and because the ncdf coordinates refer to the centers of the cells, whereas `xmn`, `xmx`, `ymn`, and `ymx` refer to the borders.

You can also use the modern equivalent

```
library(terra)
r <- rast('file.nc')
```

And to get the minimum value for each day, you can do

```
x <- tapp(r, "days", min)
```

Comment: Just so simple! I solved the memory problem using r_brick <- brick('file.nc', "mn2t"). Now my code works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Robert Hijmans This answer does not aggregate the hourly data to the daily minimum so this is at best a partial answer

Comment: @Patrick it solved the problem, even if different from the title of the question. See `terra::tapp` if you are looking for aggregating over time.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to walk you through it step-by-step using standard arrays.

**The data file**

Your data file conforms to the [CF Metadata Conventions](http://cfconventions.org), as revealed by the global attribute. Most climate observations and predictions are distributed following this convention (with some important exceptions). This means that you can assume a number of things about the file, such as the presence of `longitude`, `latitude` and `time` dimensions (among possible others) that define the data that is stored in the form of a 3-dimensional array for one or more variables. The data is also stored in that dimension order in the file.

**Reading the data in chunks**

If the data file is too large to load into memory in its entirety, you can do so in chunks and process these before reading more data. You should always do so in the order of the dimensions because that ensures a fast read from the file. (Crude benchmarking shows that reading along a meridian (lat-time) for the full time dimension is about 7x slower than reading along a parallel (lon-time), which itself is about 7x slower than reading a time slice (lon-lat)). In this case that means you read slices of the `time` dimension.

**Calendar**

The file uses the `gregorian` calendar at an `hour`ly time step. If you are **certain** that there are no gaps in the `time` dimension (for every day there are 24 slices and there are no missing days) you can use simple arithmetic like you used above, but you are probably better off with [package `CFtime`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=CFtime) which can deal with all CF calendars (there are 9 of them) and gaps in the time series.

**Solution to memory limitation and aggregation to daily minimum**

This solution is intentionally lengthy to accommodate any missing days or observations.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(CFtime)

nc_data <- nc_open("file.nc")

# Read in the details of the `time` dimension
cf <- CFtime(nc_data$dim$time$units, nc_data$dim$time$calendar, nc_data$dim$time$vals)

# Make a factor of all days in the file, then find the starting index and the
# number of observations per day in the time dimension
days <- CFfactor(cf, "day")         # Missing days not a problem 
nobs <- tabulate(days)              # Missing observations not a problem
h1 <- cumsum(nobs) - nobs[1] + 1

# Create the array of daily minimum values, all NA values
tmin <- array(dim = c(nc_data$dim$longitude$length, nc_data$dim$latitude$length, nlevels(days)))

# Loop through the time dimension, day by day
for (d in 1:nlevels(days)) {
  hrs <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "mn2t", start = c(1, 1, h1[d]), count = c(-1, -1, nobs[d]))
  tmin[, , d] <- apply(hrs, 1:2, min)
}

# Set the dimension names
dimnames(tmin) <- list(nc_data$dim$longitude$vals, nc_data$dim$latitude$vals, levels(days))

nc_close(nc_data)
```

The `tmin` array contains the daily minimum temperature for every day that there is at least one observation. With this same code pattern you can calculate other interesting properties of the daily temperature, such as the hour of the day with the minimum temperature. Also possible, if the number of observations drop below a certain number the daily minimum is not calculated so you should put an `NA` in the result.

You can trivially convert this array to a `terra::SpatRaster` with the `terra::rast()` function but you'd have to figure out whether your data file has "point" or "cell" data to set the extent right. The metadata you showed does not provide any clues in this regard.

**More memory**

If you have enough RAM to do everything in memory, the above reduces to:

```
nc_data <- nc_open("file.nc")
cf <- CFtime(nc_data$dim$time$units, nc_data$dim$time$calendar, nc_data$dim$time$vals)
days <- CFfactor(cf, "day")
tmin <- aperm(apply(ncvar_get(nc_data, "mn2t"), 1:2, tapply, days, min), c(2, 3, 1))
dimnames(tmin) <- list(nc_data$dim$longitude$vals, nc_data$dim$latitude$vals, levels(days))
nc_close(nc_data)
```

Maybe upgrade your hardware?